# How do i create a fetch service to retrieve sprint reports from JIRA?Can someone help me with the 2nd step in the pic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

https://ibb.co/Rjhwzfm

So i have to create a fetch service to retrieve sprint reports(basically data) from JIRA using the JIRA rest api so far have done this using REST template in springboot

SpringBootApplication.java

````
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SprintBootApplication {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SprintBootApplication.class);

public static void main(String args[]) {
 SpringApplication.run(SprintBootApplication.class);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
 return builder.build();
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
 return args -> {
  JiraDataFields data = restTemplate.getForObject(
    "https://jira.mtvi.com/rest/api/2/search?fields=issuetype,customfield_10280,parent,key,summary,status,timeestimate,aggregatetimeoriginalestimate,assignee,subtasks&jql=project", JiraDataFields.class);
  log.info(data.toString());
 };
}
}```

JiraDataFields.class

```package com.sprint.SprintBoot;

public class JiraDataFields {

private int id;
private String workedBy;


}```
````